# Google API file permissions?

Tags: .net, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to compile the following code, based entirely on code found on Google Drive APIs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet) and [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder). I was prompted to allow permission in a browser, but then got an exception that reads:

*An unhandled exception of type 'Google.GoogleApiException' occurred in Google.Apis.dll*

*Additional information: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Insufficient Permission [403]*

The code:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace DriveQuickstart
{
  class Program
  {
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      UserCredential credential;

      using (var stream =
      new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
      {
        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
        System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

        credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
      }

      // Create Drive API service.
      var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
      });

      var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
      {
        Name = "Invoices",
        MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
      };

      var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata);
      request.Fields = "id";
      var file = request.Execute();
      Console.WriteLine("Folder ID: " + file.Id);

      Console.Read();
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oversight, sorry. I changed `DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly` to `DriveService.Scope.DriveFile`

After the change above, I had to navigate to the `C:\users\UserName\Documents\.credentials\drive-dotnet-quickstart.json` folder, delete the file there: `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user`. It will re-create upon re-execution.